# How to use scrapy to scrape google play reviews of applications?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, google-play, scrapy

I wrote this spider to scrape reviews of apps from google play. I am partially successful in this. I am able to extract the name, date, and review only.

My questions:

- How to get all the reviews as I am only getting only 41.
- How to get the rating from the `<div>`?

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    rating = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()
  

class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "gaana"
    allowed_domains = ["play.google.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gaana&hl=en"]
    # rules = (
    # Rule(
        # SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('search=jabong&page=1/+',)),
        # callback="parse_start_url",
        # follow=True),
    # )

def parse(self, response):
    sites = response.xpath('//div[@class="single-review"]')
    items = []

    for site in sites:
        item = CompItem()
        item['data'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="review-body"]/text()').extract()
        item['name'] = site.xpath('.//div/div/span[@class="author-name"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
        item['date'] = site.xpath('.//span[@class="review-date"]/text()').extract()[0]
        item['rating'] = site.xpath('div[@class="review-info-star-rating"]/aria-label/text()').extract()
        
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry,I didn't have any clue about this !

Comment: Technically if you're accessing the site, you've already agreed to their TOS.

Comment: So Should I drop my plan?

Comment: That's your call. We are but programmers, not lawyers. I wouldn't build a business on this idea though.

Comment: I was just scraping them to check if it can be scraped or not?They don't have provided with any API also.!

Comment: You never know what one can make of a good data. #calmdownbro

Comment: I think there are many businesses built on this. Review Aggregation sites like Sensor Tower, Mobile Action... how do you think they get their data? They must be simply scraping the site.

Comment: @user1406716 exactly

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
 item['rating'] = site.xpath('div[@class="review-info-star-rating"]/aria-label/text()').extract()
```

should it not be something like:

```
item['rating'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="review-info-star-rating"]/aria-label/text()').extract()
```

?? dunno if it will work, but try :)

Comment: What have you changed exactly?

Comment: added the ".//" before the div :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one out:

```
item['rating'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="tiny-star star-rating-non-editable-container"]/@aria-label').extract()
```